# Can history.replaceState replace post/redirect/get?

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser-history, post-redirect-get

I have never liked the [post-redirect-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern because it requires an extra roundtrip between the client and the server, it often requires using the stateful and (in my opinion) hacky [flash pattern](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/sessions-cookies-and-authentication), and, although one of the main reasons it is used is to prevent duplicate form submissions, it doesn't actually do a good job of that since duplicate submissions are still possible in the window before the redirect finishes.  (This can be prevented by taking precautions on the client, but these precautions make post-redirect-get unnecessary, except for the extremely rare case of browsers with JavaScript turned off.)

However, one compelling reason to use the pattern has been that one usually wants the client to see a different URL from the URL posted to after the post.  I have recently experimented with dropping the post/redirect/get pattern and just using `history.replaceState` to set the desired URL on the client.  I know this won't work on IE9 and below, but I am OK with that.  But is there some other gaping problem with this approach that I am overlooking?

Comment: Have you found any answers elsewhere since this was posted?

Comment: Not really.  My sense is that the web developers who would be keen to use `history.replaceState` are often not doing traditional form submits in the first place.  They are using AJAX and working in a more SPA style.